# How do I use preg_match() to extract words marked with ## from a string and then put them in html tag(s)?

Tags: php, preg-match

How to get from **here**:

The #quick# brown fox jumps over the #lazy# dog

to **here**:

The **span-tag** quick **/span-tag** brown fox jumps over the **span-tag** lazy **/span-tag** dog

?

And sometimes it`s only:

*The quick brown fox jumps over the #lazy# dog*

so a dynamic solution would be great.

My output right now is only *quick*

```
<?php preg_match("/(?<=#).*?(?=#)/", "The #quick# brown fox jumps over the #lazy# dog", $match);
  var_dump($match)
?>
```

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps using `preg_replace` and a simpler pattern would work:

```php
$str = 'The #quick# brown fox jumps over the #lazy# dog';
$newStr = preg_replace('/#([^#]*)#/', '<span>$1</span>', $str);
```

Produces

```html
The <span>quick</span> brown fox jumps over the <span>lazy</span> dog
```

Comment: Thanks a ton, works like a charm. I've replaced # with ; to avoid strange &35; code fracture.